# How to eliminate acronym list from a journal file?

Tags: overleaf, ieeetran, journal

I'm writing a journal paper in IEEE format using Overleaf. I'm using the `\usepackage{acronym}` package to define acronyms in a separate latex file and then call them in the main document I'm writing. However, when I generate the main file, the acronym list is displayed first, and then my document. I want to generate my document only and not the acronym list.

Here is part of the code I wrote

```
\documentclass[journal, 12pt, onecolumn, draftcls]{IEEEtran}

% *** GRAPHICS RELATED PACKAGES ***
%
\ifCLASSINFOpdf
  % \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
  % declare the path(s) where your graphic files are
  % \graphicspath{{../pdf/}{../jpeg/}}
  % and their extensions so you won't have to specify these with
  % every instance of \includegraphics
  % \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.jpeg,.png}
\else
  % or other class option (dvipsone, dvipdf, if not using dvips). graphicx
  % will default to the driver specified in the system graphics.cfg if no
  % driver is specified.
  % \usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
  % declare the path(s) where your graphic files are
  % \graphicspath{{../eps/}}
  % and their extensions so you won't have to specify these with
  % every instance of \includegraphics
  % \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps}
\fi
% graphic was written by David Carlisle and Sebastian Rahtz. It is
% required if you want graphics, photos, etc. graphicx.sty is already
% installed on most LaTeX systems. The latest version and documentation
% can be obtained at: 
% http://www.ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
% Another good source of documentation is "Using Imported Graphics in
% LaTeX2e" by Keith Reckdahl which can be found at:
% http://www.ctan.org/pkg/epslatex
%
% latex, and pdflatex in dvi mode, support graphics in encapsulated
% postscript (.eps) format. pdflatex in pdf mode supports graphics
% in .pdf, .jpeg, .png and .mps (metapost) formats. Users should ensure
% that all non-photo figures use a vector format (.eps, .pdf, .mps) and
% not a bitmapped formats (.jpeg, .png). The IEEE frowns on bitmapped formats
% which can result in "jaggedy"/blurry rendering of lines and letters as
% well as large increases in file sizes.
%
% You can find documentation about the pdfTeX application at:
% http://www.tug.org/applications/pdftex





% *** MATH PACKAGES ***
\usepackage{appendix}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{array}
%\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{graphic}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\graphicspath{{Figures/}{../Figures/}}
\usepackage{gensymb,bm}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[cmex10]{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
%\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{acronym} 
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}


\begin{document}

\title{Impact of noisy measurements with Fourier-based evaluation on condensed channel parameters}
\input{acro_list}

\end{document}
```

The acronym file I created is as follows:

```
\begin{acronym} % Give the longest label here so that the list is nicely aligned
\acro{RMS}{Root Mean Square}
\acro{RMSDS}{Root Mean Square Delay Spread}
\acro{MC}{MonteCarlo}
\acro{MPC}{Multipath Component}
\acro{HRPE}{High-Resolution Parameter Extraction}
\acro{MUSIC}{Multiple Signal Classification}
\end{acronym}
```

I appreciate your kind help on this question.

Cheers,

Jorge